# Setting the group option dynamically not working in ng-grid 2.0.7

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I am creating a simple grid and getting the data from a json for both the columnDefs and the groups.

Setting columnDefs works properly, with

```
data: 'gridData' // Where gridData is $scope.gridData.
```

but setting

```
groups : $scope.groupsFieldsFromServer // This is ['fieldname']
```

is not working, it is just displays the grid as is, but the intended pre-grouping is not happening.

Any help?

Comment: if you trace $scope.gropusFieldsFromServer before assigning it to the grid is it already populated with this value?  If not I would guess the ng-grid code isn't watching for changes on the groups object and isn't getting the data when it is resolved.

Comment: @shaunhusain I hard coded the data just to check, like this `groups : ['fieldname']`, this also is not working. I want to pre-group the grid. I am not sure but I am thinking since my columnDefs are variables, can that we a problem?